# How to change node-red-dashboard graph min and max value of Y axis directly on the UI?

Tags: node-red

I am trying to create a node-red dashboard with a graph and two numeric inputs. These inputs are to control the min and max value of the Y-axis.
If I create a node to supply the values to the graph, the value always received as payload for the graph, thus become a new data series. What I want to do is to supply a value to change the min/max value of the Y axis. That value will be supplied from the two numeric inputs.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated here [UI Widget configuration via msg.ui_control](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-dashboard/blob/master/config-fields.md) : properties of ui widget nodes can be set by using a msg.ui_control property on a msg. Multiple properties of the node can be set at the same time. eg { "min":10, "max":50 }.  Specifically for the line charts ui_chart (you called it graph) the properties are: ymin and ymax.